# JavaScript OOP: Objects change their prototype (for all other objects using the same prototype)

Tags: javascript, oop, prototype, javascript-objects

```
function NamedRoundedBlock(){
    var name = this.makeFeild("name");
    name.className = "Block NamedRound name";
    this.element.className = "Block NamedRound root";
    this.element.appendChild(name);
}
NamedRoundedBlock.prototype = new Block();
NamedRoundedBlock.prototype.constructor = NamedRoundedBlock;
```

There's the code, anyone know what I've done wrong?

My problem is that if I make two NamedRoundedBlock objects and change the this.element property of one (by changing an attribute or something) the other's will change too.

Also, a little additional detail, `this.makeFeild` and `this.element` are both set in Block

Comment: I have no idea what you did wrong, because you didn't say what the problem is.

Comment: The title is throwing me off, too. Objects don't magically change their prototypes. Can you clarify?

Comment: Sorry, I'll edit the question a bit

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.  JavaScript is behaving as advertised here.  The prototype is just the place for shared properties.  Changes you make in the prototype are seen by all objects.

Comment: That's a bit annoying. What's the best way around it?

Comment: I'll write an answer, once sec.

Comment: Answered but question just got marked as a dupe.

Comment: You have just found one of the reasons why you should not create an instance of Parent to set the prototype part of Child inheritance. You can still do `Parent.apply(this,arguments);` and shadow Parent instance specific members but you still should not do `Child.prototype=new Parent();` use Object.create with a polyfil if needed: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16063711/1641941

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out [Traditional OOP Inheritance in JavaScript](http://blog.slaks.net/2013-09-03/traditional-inheritance-in-javascript/)

The above blog post may help answer some of your questions.

It elaborates particularly on defining a new constructor for an object, which "inherits" from a parent.  Is that one of your questions?  Take this for example:

```
NamedRoundedBlock.prototype = Object.create(
    Block.prototype,
        {
            "constructor": { 
                configurable: true,
                enumerable: false,
                writable: true,
                value: 'NamedRoundedBlock'
            }
        }
);
```

The above created an object based on *Block*'s prototype, but it defines its own constructor, and also sets it as *not enumerable*.

Also, should the first line be something like this?:

```
function NamedRoundedBlock() {
    this.name = this.makeFeild("name");
    //etc.
```

Additionally, independent of the issue, I'd be careful with the spelling of "Feild" (spelled "Field"), as spelling issues can sometimes cause hard-to-find bugs later in the code.

Comment: Links are bad answers! Try to elaborate in your post, as links can and do change.

Comment: Second parameter in Object.create does not work in older browsers and a good polyfil should throw an error: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create#Polyfill (look at throw new Error)

Answer (score 1):

The prototype is the place for shared properties.

Consider:

```
var protoCircle - {x: 0, y: 0, radius: 1}
```

This means every circle will have these properties as *defaults*.  So if I make circle with that prototype:

```
var c1 = Object.create(protoCircle);
c1.x = 3;

var c2 = Object.create(protoCircle);
c2.y = 5;
```

then circle `c1` is at (3,0) with radius 1 and `c2` is at (0,5) with radius 1.  That's because `c1` has only one *own property* (`x`) and two *inherited properties* (`y` and `radius`) which it picks up from its prototype.  If I change `protoCircle.radius` then that change will be seen by the two circles.  That is the way JavaScript is designed! This design allows a whole bunch of objects to share a default value so you don't have to store it in each object.  You just put the properties unique to each object inside each object and let the default properties be shared in the prototype.  In the case above, if 99% of the circles have a radius of 1, then we don't have to store radii in our individual circles.

In your case you put a property called `element` in a prototype.  All objects that share that prototype will have the same value for `element`.  So if you say

```
x.element.className = 'something'
```

then that does effectively make `y.element.className` be `something` as well, assuming `y` shares the same prototype as `x`.

If you want each of the named rounded blocks to have *different* elements then you need to do this:

```
function NamedRoundedBlock(){
    ...
    this.element = {}
    this.element.className = "Block NamedRound root";
    this.element.appendChild(name);
}
```